# How do I fix WRITE FPDMA QUEUED messages if the SMART report isn't showing any errors?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart

This is an OCZ Vertex SSD. I'm told that the first value (raw read error rate) is irrelevant for SSDs. I'm getting a lot of "WRITE FPDMA QUEUED" errors in terminal (why I'm in terminal is another issue, I tried changing the kernel and now it won't run the old kernel and the new one is not compatible with Mint 20).

The OS has been behaving oddly (3+ second delay on mouse clicks some of the time, ssh password prompt is sometimes delayed by several seconds). I suspect this "WRITE FPDMA QUEUED" is the issue.

This machine was previously running Mint 19 with no issues. But a couple of weeks I moved and had to switch the machine over to using wifi instead of ethernet. Ran into issues connecting so, long story short, here I am in Mint 20 with 3 problems (no wifi, hard disk, ethernet cable running across my floor) instead of 1.

Tried the solutions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/952148/failed-command-write-fpdma-queued-cause-of-server-running-slow). No luck.

This is a bookshelf system, an MSI Cubi, so I can't switch SATA ports or anything like that. Plus, it seems unlikely to be a hardware issue since it coincided with changing the OS.

Am I missing something obvious in the health check?

[image: health check]

[image: errors]

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667957/whats-the-best-way-to-confirm-that-my-hard-drive-is-not-seeing-write-fpdma-queu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole thing screams "hardware issues" and it looks more like the beginning of it coincided with your *move* rather than with your upgrading your distro.

So here is what we can see from your images:

Your system is sending commands to the drive and they are timing out. The drive itself, never having properly received the command, never tried to do anything and thus has no error to log.

I suspect that your SATA cable has come loose or somehow been damaged. The first thing to try is replacing it. Beyond that, it may be that the SATA *connectors* on the drive or the motherboard have been damaged. If that is the case, you are pretty screwed. Actually testing either of them, though, requires replacing the other component with a known good one. In the meantime, inspect them closely to see if anything looks damaged. You might be able to see something.

Comment: OK good call I will try replacing  / reconnecting the cable

Comment: if I plug this in to another computer what would be a way to definitely confirm that the drive is definitely not the issue?

Comment: @jcollum Spend some time writing to it.

Comment: used `dd` to write to it ([instructions I followed](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-test-disk-performance-with-dd-command/)) then checked dmesg. It wrote 4GB of data in 2.6s, 1.6 GB/s. No messages in dmesg about failures. Maybe I need to look somewhere else?

Comment: Now you try another disk on the suspect motherboard/cable.

Comment: OK but I didn't see any issues when I ran the test, so if I get a new drive and run the same test I haven't really proved anything. I need a way of detecting these failures. Do you know where I can see the logs that have "WRITE FPDMA QUEUED" from a terminal running from the install disk? Or some test that will show they are happening?

Comment: ah I think this has a solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/623238/29679

Comment: I think this was a red herring caused by the kernel being upgraded when it shouldn't have. I also cleaned the contacts on the drive, that could be it. Either way, it's not happening after I reinstalled the OS (spent an hour trying to downgrade the kernel, gave up) and cleaned those contacts.